# ionic & LeafletJS set marker

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, leaflet

I am trying to set markers to my `$scope.map` variable with

```
L.marker([location.lat,location.lng]).addTo($scope.map);
```

, but I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: t.addLayer is not a function at
>   o.Marker.o.Class.extend.addTo (leaflet.js:7) at mapController.js:82

I don't know why, because I am basically doing the same as in http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons.html

and as it is specified in the API
http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker

I wanted to add custom icons, but now got hung up here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomand you to add [angular-leaflet-directives](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive) that are the leaflet packaged for angular JS.

Then to add a marker, do the following :

- create your marker

  ```
    var iconTemplate = {
     'lat': lat, // your lat value
     'lng': lng, // your lng value
     'focus': false,
     'layer': layerValue, // if you add your marker to a layer
     'draggable': false,
     'message': popupContent, // your popupcontent
      getMessageScope: function() {
          return $scope;
      },
      compileMessage: true,
      'icon': {
        'type': "awesomeMarker", // i use awesomeMarker for font awesome
        'icon': markerIcon, // a variable for my icon
        'markerColor': markerColor // a variable for my color
       }
  };
  ```
- add your marker to your marker list (binded to HTML)

  ```
    $scope.markers.push(iconTemplate)
  ```

That's it

Comment: Thanks! This is great! However, I do not understand how I would install this package? I don't see the node installation commands for this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can install it with bower : bower install angular-leaflet-directive --save

Comment: How can I combine Ionic and Bower?

Comment: bower is a package management and ionic a framework. You can indeed load ionic with bower (bower install ionic --save).

Comment: Sorry, I should have said Node.js . I wrote Ionic. That would make for two package management frameworks... ?

Comment: npm install bower ;). Bower is a widly used package management for webtools (css, js, fonts etc...) http://bower.io/

Comment: Yeah, I already tried that but it now screwed up my project, it doesnt find the leaftlet.js file. I'll have to fix it with the new, adjusted installation. Thanks for your help! :D

Comment: add angular-leaflet-directive AFTER leaflet.js and AFTER angular.js

Comment: hm, not sure about this now. I had a fully functioning ionic project that I took from here https://github.com/calendee/ionic-leafletjs-map-demo and expanded from there. Now it's messed up... :P Maybe I'll have to restart the project... ?

Comment: this project already has angular-leaflet-directive. No need to had it or d/L it. Just create your markers ;)

Comment: Do'h ! Should have known that! How can I fall back to the previous? I just ran 'bower install angular-leaflet-directive --save' before and it's messed up now.

Comment: I don't think that it messed up oyur project doing this command as it has normally installed all angular-leaflet directive into a specific directory (default : bower_component) and is NEVER removing files or editing your index.html. I think you made other stuff that messed up your project ;)

Comment: Not sure, I just ran the command and then it wouldnt find the leaflet.js anymore. I now fell back to the previous version and it works again. Didnt test the markers yet.